# plink - dealing with special charters in password

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

All,

I have a script that is using plink to connect to ~300 routers.  I last used it to update a password for an admin account.  Short is, password containing ! is failing.

I can SSH to the router with the password containing ! just can't connect using plink.  I have tried replacing ! with %21.  Tried escaping with ! and ^!.  Nothing is working.

Thoughts?

Comment: pscp works fine with the password containing a ! 

This is going to turn into a real problem!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant parts of your script.

Answer (score -1):

Yea, that was a lot of nonsense to end-up with double ^

So.  Escape ! with ^^

Example
plink -pw abc^^!

Comment: That makes little sense on its own. There must be some more complex syntax around that.